# Access Pandas MultiIndex column by name

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, multi-index

I have a spreadsheet imported with pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('my_spreadsheet.xlsx',header = [0,1],index_col=0,sheetname='Sheet1')
```

The output of df.columns is:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'MR 1', u'MR 10', u'MR 11', u'MR 12', u'MR 13', u'MR 14', u'MR 15', u'MR 16', u'MR 17', u'MR 18', u'MR 19', u'MR 2', u'MR 20', u'MR 21', u'MR 22', u'MR 3', u'MR 4', u'MR 5', u'MR 6', u'MR 7', u'MR 8', u'MR 9'], [u'BIRADS', u'ExamDesc', u'completedDTTM']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]],
       names=[None, u'De-Identified MRN'])
```

I have been trying to access the values of **column named 'De-Identified MRN'**, but can't seem to find the way to do this.

What I have tried (based on similar posts):

```
[in] df.index.get_level_values('De-Identified MRN')

[out] KeyError: 'Level De-Identified MRN must be same as name (None)'
```

and

```
[in] df.index.unique(level='De-Identified MRN')

[out] KeyError: 'Level De-Identified MRN must be same as name (None)'
```

UPDATE:
The following did the trick for some reason. I really do not understand the format of the MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe:

```
pd.Series(df.index)
```

Comment: `df.index.get_level_values(level=1)`

Comment: Your first approach works for me, as does your second approach

Comment: @Wen that returns: IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Answer (score 4):

By using your data

```
s="MultiIndex(levels=[[u'MR 1', u'MR 10', u'MR 11', u'MR 12', u'MR 13', u'MR 14', u'MR 15', u'MR 16', u'MR 17', u'MR 18', u'MR 19', u'MR 2', u'MR 20', u'MR 21', u'MR 22', u'MR 3', u'MR 4', u'MR 5', u'MR 6', u'MR 7', u'MR 8', u'MR 9'], [u'BIRADS', u'ExamDesc', u'completedDTTM']],labels=[[0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]],names=[None, u'De-Identified MRN'])"
idx=eval(s, {}, {'MultiIndex': pd.MultiIndex})
df=pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df.index.get_level_values(level=1) # df.index.get_level_values('De-Identified MRN')

Out[336]: 
Index(['ExamDesc', 'completedDTTM', 'BIRADS', 'ExamDesc', 'completedDTTM',
       'BIRADS', 'ExamDesc', 'completedDTTM', 'BIRADS', 'ExamDesc',...
```

Also if all above still does not work , try

```
df.reset_index()['De-Identified MRN']
```

Comment: I get the same output for the code in your post, but I am not sure what is happening and the output is not what I want. I just want to retrieve the values stored under the column named 'De-Identified MRN'. In a normal pandas dataframe it would work with df['De-Identified MRN']. I just need the analogue for a MultiIndex one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[[u'MR 1', u'MR 10', u'MR 11', u'MR 12', u'MR 13', u'MR 14', u'MR 15', u'MR 16', u'MR 17', u'MR 18', u'MR 19', u'MR 2', u'MR 20', u'MR 21', u'MR 22', u'MR 3', u'MR 4', u'MR 5', u'MR 6', u'MR 7', u'MR 8', u'MR 9'], [u'BIRADS', u'ExamDesc', u'completedDTTM']],
    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]],
    names=[None, u'De-Identified MRN']
)

midx.levels[1]  # returns the following
Index(['BIRADS', 'ExamDesc', 'completedDTTM'], dtype='object', name='De-Identified MRN')

midx.levels[1].values # returns the following
array(['BIRADS', 'ExamDesc', 'completedDTTM'], dtype=object)
```